# Android app and native desktop app comunication

Tags: java, android, communication, wifi, native

I have a native application written in C++. I would like to write an Android application that would be able to comunicate with my native application when user is in connected to the same WiFi network as my PC.

How this things are done. I mean what technologies are used behind it. Maybe you have some samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a peer-to-peer library, like [AllJoyn](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/alljoyn-p2p) from Qualcomm. The idea is that both your PC and the Android device will use TCP/IP to communicate with each other. You still need a protocol above that however that will handle discovery, session establishment and exchange of data.

Comment: Wouldn't be a problem that one application is written in Java and one in C++?

Comment: No, as long as you have implementations of the protocol in both environments. I believe that AllJoyn has both C++ and Java versions.